# Remove default page title suffix from home page (or any specific page)

Tags: magento-2.1, seo, page, title

I have been scouring the forums for the right way of changing the page title for a specific page or layout in Magento 2 but many answers rely on action methods which are now deprecated.

Essentially, I have set the store up so the suffix for each page title is "- CompanyName" but I would like to know how to create an exception for this for the home page (and other specific landing pages). I have changed the page title in a custom layout file successfully but the suffix is still appended to the end. Is there a sensible way of stopping this from happening on a specific page, like the home page?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @themanwhoknowstheman see below :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to overwrite **Magento\Framework\View\Page\Title::addConfigValues** function.

**etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="YourVendor_YourModule" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Framework"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Page\Title" type="YourVendor\YourModule\Model\View\Page\Title" />
</config>
```

**YourVendor/YourModule/Model/View/Page/Title.php**

```
<?php
namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Model\View\Page;

/**
* Page title
*
* @api
* @since 100.0.2
*/
class Title extends \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Title
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
     */
    private $request;

    /**
     * Title constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;

        parent::__construct($scopeConfig);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $title
     * @return string
     */
    protected function addConfigValues($title)
    {
        $preparedTitle = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                'design/head/title_prefix',
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            ) . ' ' . $title;
        $postfix = ' ' . $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                'design/head/title_suffix',
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            );
        if ($this->request->getFullActionName() == 'cms_index_index') {
            $postfix = '';
        }
        return trim($preparedTitle . $postfix);
    }
}
```

Replace **YourVendor_YourModule** with your own vendor and module names.

Comment: Feel like a plugin should be able to more simply handle this but haven't figured one out yet.